# Конвертация в режиме ввел-получил

Tags: java, javafx

Делаю программу Конвертер.Подскажите как мне реализовать метод что бы при вводе числа в одном  поле сразу же выводилось число это же число в другом поле?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

```
package ru.java-simple.swap;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Swap {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int tn=0;
    int kg = 0;
    int gr = 0;
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    System.out.print("Enter numeric [tn]: ");
    tn = scan.nextInt();
    
    System.out.println(tn);
    System.out.println(kg = tn*1000);
    System.out.println(gr = kg*1000);

}

}
```

Алгоритм думаю понятен на уровне консоли.

Comment: слушатель добавляйте для поля, в которое вводите число. именно этот слушатель по нажатию на кнопку будет писать данные в другое поле на основании введенных данных

Answer (score 0):

Добавляете слушатель текста на изменяемое поле, внутри слушателя проверяете валидность нового значения, выбираете нужные конвертер, если под это задумывался выпадающий список, ну и записываете результат в результирующие поля.

```
source.textProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> target.setText(convert(newValue)));
```